# Comparing values within columns in SAS

Tags: sas, comparison

I have not been able to find an answer to this question, although there are some similar ones.

I have a large dataset (9 million rows) that contains

- an id column ("id"),
- an identifier if "id" is new for that period ("new_id"),
- a latitude column ("lat")
- and a longitude column ("long").

In SAS, what I want to do is, using the geodist function, compare the distance between each row and create an indicator, "nearby", that equals 1 if the distance between that id and any other id is less than 50 miles and "new_id" = 1 for the other row.

Below is some pseudo code of what I'm trying to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Pseudo code:

```
For all_rows1 in data
    For all_rows2 in data
        if (geo_dist(all_rows1(lat), all_rows1(long), all_rows2(lat), all_rows2(long) < 50) 
        and all_rows2(new_id) = 1 
            then all_rows1(nearby) = 1
```

Comment: You need to post some sample data, this sounds like a distance matrix with an attempt at sparsity. It will be a lot of data in the end. http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/stat/ex_code/132/clusdist.html

Comment: Here's how to calculate the distances , but I'm not sure wha tyou want as an output. What happens if you have 2 stores within 50? https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Using-Proc-Distance-to-Calculate-Geodesic-Distance/m-p/228482/highlight/true#M54292

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. As long as there's 1 store, it gets a "1". The link you sent, though, I believe solves my problem. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: What roll does the "period" play in this story? Do you periodically have a new file? What percentage of your row has `new_id = 1`?